Shrinkwrap broken in render
I´m trying Shirinkwrap on the shoe project that I´m doing.
And in the shading view it looks totally fine, but somehow it does look broken when I get final render.

This is the shading view

And this is the render result.
Anyone know why this occurs?
Thank you in advance.

Just a guess: there is a Subdivision Surface modifier with different levels for viewport and rendering...? A screenshot of the modifier stack would be helpful to rule this out or confirm it.

Wait, you wrote it is okay in the shading view. But in the 2nd screenshot, the shading view, the "+" pattern has bare spots while it looks okay in the first screenshot. But there the sole of the heel looks "broken".  So there are problems in both screenshots, right?

By the way, which object uses the Shrinkwrap modifier? I think you need to add more details to clarify the issue.

Hi! I made one + shape obejct and used array modifier. I checked the render view and it was actually same as viewport. also now I see my ousole part render is broken too! it may happens because of the render resolution?
